Understanding pydantic output parser from an LLM output
I have a problem understanding output parsers (especially (pydanticoutputparser) and what are there capabilities. I make a query from my llm to parse some data with this pydantic object :

class Diploma(BaseModel):
    diploma_name: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="diploma name")
    institution: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="institution")
    city: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="City of the institution.")
    issue_date: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Issue date of the diploma")
    relevant_coursework: Optional[List[str]] = Field(None, description="relevant courseworks")

class Education(BaseModel):
    diplomas: List[Diploma] = Field(default_factory=list, description="List of diplomas.")


then i prompt my llm with a query that asks data to be in this exact structure and i output it from a local llm in json mode :
{
    "diplomas": [
        {
            "diploma_name": "",
            "institution": "",
            "city": "",
            "issue_date": "",
            "relevant_coursework": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Up until now my code works 6 times out of 10. Each diploma is retrieved and put in education perfectly.
Here is my problem and my question : 4 times out of 10 it doesn't work because the output of the llm isn't structured right so it isn't stored in the class object. I thought that by using an output parser the data would have been structured in a fixed way by the llm. Just like a rule and the rule can't be broken, but I must be misunderstanding something somewhere. Could somebody possibly explain how pydantic works and if there are any solutions to have an llm output that works almost 10 times out of 10 ?
Also, I'm sorry to have not included a lot of code, I'm doing an internship in a startup company and don't want to leak too much of code, this is why I'm trying to understand the concepts rather than correcting code.
Thanks a lot for your help !
I read lots of documentations on langchain pydanticoutputparser and jsonoutputparser. The issue seems to come from the llm output itself.

I believe there is a misunderstanding about the purpose of Pydantic models. They are primarily used for validation, ensuring that the JSON object conforms to the fields described in the model. The task of producing structured output, however, depends entirely on the LLM model.
One common issue with LLMs is that they may hallucinate, adding extraneous text to the prefix or suffix of the JSON output. To address this, you can either implement custom parsers to clean up the output or use the from_json method provided in pydantic_core.
below is one such implementation.
from typing import Any
from pydantic_core import from_json

def extract_and_parse_json(input_string: str) -> Any:

    # Find the position of the first '{'
    json_start = input_string.find('{')
    if json_start == -1:
        raise ValueError("No JSON dictionary found in the input string.")
    # Extract the JSON content starting from the first '{'
    json_content = input_string[json_start:]
    try:
        # Convert JSON content to bytes and parse it using from_json
        json_bytes = json_content.encode("utf-8")
        parsed_data = from_json(json_bytes,allow_partial=True)
        return parsed_data
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Error parsing JSON content: {e}")


